# Checking QSQLITE Database in Terminal

Tags: sqlite, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I created the database as follows:

```
QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
database.setDatabaseName("./data/Movies.db");
database.open();
```

I then connect to my phone using telnet. Then I type in sqlite3. How can I search for my database. if I type .databases, I do not see my database

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide a code sample (or a link) to what you're trying to reference? I don't understand what you're asking for. Creating a DB in a BB device is **[pretty trivial](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/Create_a_SQLite_database_761831_11.jsp)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how the `sqlite3` command-line tool works.

You have to give the path to the database as parameter when starting it, e.g.:

```sh
$ sqlite3 /path/to/my/database.db
```

Comment: oh, so should I type in sqlite3 /data/Movies.db?

Comment: You should use the complete path of your database file.